# Ошибка при работе с Docker и Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, dockerfile

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём проблема? Запускаю команды docker build . и получаю ошибку, представленную на скриншоте. Мой код файла Dockerfile:

```
FROM node

WORKDIR /disk-sharing



COPY . .

RUN npm install

RUN node db-init.js

EXPOSE 3033

CMD ["node", "disksharing.js"]
```

Ошибка именно в строке "RUN node db-init.js", поскольку без неё всё работает. Файл db-init.js расположен в корне проекта рядом с Dockerfile. Если запустить команду node db-init.js через терминал, то всё работает без ошибок.

[image: Скриншот ошибки]

Comment: скорее всего последняя строка должна быть такой `CMD ["node", "/disk-sharing/disksharing.js"]`. хотя это и не совсем совпадает с текстом ошибки

Comment: возвращает тот же результат

Comment: ошибка именно в строке "RUN node db-init.js", поскольку без неё всё работает. Файл db-init.js расположен в корне проекта рядом с Dockerfile

Comment: а, как я пропустил. вот так тоже нужно попробовать указать полный путь `RUN node /disk-sharing/db-init.js`

Comment: к сожалению так тоже не работает(

Comment: присмотрелся внимательно к логам (вот как раз поэтому, текст нужно текстом, а не картинкой, не все люди имеют супермониторы и 146% зрение) - а там ошибка прям написана модуль bcrypt не смогло загрузить нормально. прикольно, но тут я даже не знаю, может образ для ноды плохо подготовлен

Comment: Попробуйте решение отсюда [bcrypt invalid elf header when running node app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15809611/bcrypt-invalid-elf-header-when-running-node-app)

Comment: Спасибо! Буду разбираться

Comment: Скорее всего у вас используются модули установленные на хосте внутри докера. А они не совместимы. Удалите node_modules чтоб проверить

Comment: Сработало) Спасибо большое